# Enable - Disable a button while threading vsto for ms word

Tags: vsto, office-addins

I'am very new to threading and quite unclear as to why this is happening in my code, when I click on a button that verifies hyperlinks in my document, I start a new thread that does the verification once it starts I want to disable the ribbon button and enable it again after thread finished but this is not happening and I dont know what is the mistake .Here is what I have tried so far:

```
     public class Alpha :Ribbon1
     {
        // This method that will be called when the thread is started
        public void Beta() 
        {
             foreach() { //do something }  after this loop ,enable the button again 
             button.enable=true  //not applying 
        }             }                                                                                    

        private void button_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
                Alpha oAlpha = new Alpha();
                     // Create the thread object, passing in the Alpha.Beta method
               Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oAlpha.Beta));
                    // MessageBox.Show("Please wait till the document is checked for invalid links");
                   // Start the thread
                 oThread.Start();
             button7.Label = "Pls wait";
             button7.Enabled = false;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ribbon needs to be rendered again after enable/disable for change to take effect, you can do this by calling IRibbonUI.Invalidate()